# Queries regarding combobox.valuemember when using a custom dictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, dictionary, combobox

I have the following code as part of a WPF I am creating:

```
Dictionary<string, string[]> storeDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();

private void populateDropbox()
    {
        storeDropDown.DataSource = new BindingSource(storeDictionary, null);
        storeDropDown.DisplayMember = "Key";
        storeDropDown.ValueMember = "Value";
        storeDropDown.SelectedValue = 0;
    }
```

Note: storeDropDown is name of the combobox.

How would I get storeDropdown.Valuemember to be the first element of the string[]?

Please bare in mind this is my first program and c# is my first programming language.

If you need more info let me know, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You say you are doing WPF but the ComboBox you are using comes from winforms.
So what are you actually working on?

Assuming you are using Winforms (the ComboBox of your example) here is my solution:

1 - Create a class to encapsulate your array of string and override the ToString() method

```
internal class CustomArrayOfStrings
{
    public string[] _strings;

    public override ToString()
    {
        return _strings[0];
    }
}
```

Now your dictionary looks like something like this:

```
Dictionary<string, CustomArrayOfStrings> storeDictionary = new Dictionary<string, CustomArrayOfStrings>();
```

2- Then, to display the first element in your ComboBox you change

```
storeDropDown.DisplayMember = "Key";
```

to

```
storeDropDown.DisplayMember = "Value";
```

This will call the ToString methode of your Value wich is a CustomArrayOfStrings.

3 - If you want to manipulate the selected first element of your array, you can do it this way:

```
CustomArrayOfStrings selected = storeDropDown.SelectedValue as CustomArrayOfStrings;
string firstValue = selected._strings[0];
```

Comment: Paradise, yes you are correct I am using winforms. I will try this tonight and get back to you but it looks exactly what I'm looking for.